# Unable to Update a Label.HiddenFor field in ASP.net MVC after getting Ajax Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

In my ASP.net MVC Application. I am facing a problem and really struggling for it.

I have an edit form in a View , in that i have a label which is defined as:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxEdit", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "Success", OnFailure = "Failed",UpdateTargetId = "ChangedOn"}))
                   { %>

           <%=Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.ChangedOn)%>
           <%:Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.ChangedOn)%>
```

after Clicking on the submit buttton,the ajax request is called and server response is sent back.

But, the Problem is i was not able to update that hidden field with the server response recieved.

The problem is beacuse it is of type hidden input.
is there any other way of doing this..please help.

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html tag for hidden input to see what will happens:

```
 <input id="ChangedOnId" name="ChangedOn" type="hidden" value="<%=Model.ChangedOn%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change value of hidden input you can do this:

```
$("#ChangedOn").val(yourValue);
```

And if you want to change it's text change DisplayFor with a tag that you can select that.
I think `DisplayFor` only render a plain text of your property

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields are stored in ModelState

You can remove it

```
ModelState.Remove(nameof(Model.ChangedOn));
```